# Can not find namespace or data type NavMeshAgent Unity 3d

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, namespaces

I am trying to run simple Unity script (which is attached as a component of my object) in Visual Studio. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class BlackPawnParticleSystem : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        ParticleSystem ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem);
        var em = ps.emission;
        em.enabled = true;

        em.SetBursts(
            new ParticleSystem.Burst[]{
                new ParticleSystem.Burst(2.0f, 100),
                new ParticleSystem.Burst(4.0f, 100)
            });
    }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {

  }
}
```

The problem is that when I run it I get an error: "Can not find namespace or data type NavMeshAgent". I have read that there might be a problem with simple UnityEngine import. So I have replaced it with `using UnityEngine.AI`.

But all the classes like ParticleSystem and MonoBehavior are underlined and show the same "Can not find namespace" error like they are not in this namespace. So how I can define my namespaces imports to run the code properly?

UPDATE: full error message is

```
D:\userdata\Documents\Scene1\Assets\RPG Character Animation Pack\Code\RPGCharacterControllerFREE.cs(21,10,21,22): error CS0246: Can not find namespace or data type NavMeshAgent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't remove the `UnityEngine` import, just add the `UnityEngine.AI` import on the next line.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
```

You'll have to add this import to the actual file that is giving the error, so in this case that means you need to go to `RPGCharacterControllerFREE.cs` and add `using UnityEngine.AI;` to that file.

Comment: Even if I just add UnityEngine.AI I get the same error while execution.

Comment: If you import both UnityEngine and UnityEngine.AI, it still gives a data type missing error?

Comment: But if you only import `UnityEngine.AI` without importing `UnityEngine`, then `NavMeshAgent` no longer missing but everything else is missing? That's not proper namespace behavior, and my Unity isn't acting like that. If it's not missing when you have only `UnityEngine.AI`, then it shouldn't be missing if you have both of them.

Comment: It can't find everything else (ParticleSystem, NavMeshAgent, MonoBehavior) and NavMeshAgent too

Comment: Where are you using NavMeshAgent in this file? Can you edit the question to show the version of your code that gives the error?

Comment: I've edited the answer; you need to make the addition in the file that's giving the error. It looks like the error is coming from a different file than the one you posted.